# How to define a function that returns the position of an element of a tuple as coordinates of a referential I defined?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, python-3.x, tuples

sorry for the long code but i think its tthe only way you can understand my question. i wrote this code:

```
def key_gen1(l):

'''   function that receives a tuple of 25 letters
and then returns a tuple of tuples with 5 letters each

example: letters = ('A','B','C','D','E','F',\   
'G','H','I','J', ' ', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',\
'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Z', '.')   

key_gen1(letters) = (('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),\
('F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'), (' ', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'),\  
 ('P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'), ('U', 'V', 'X', 'Z', '.'))  '''


    key = tuple(letters[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(letters), 5))
    return key
```

So imagine that what the previous function returned forms a matrix shape key and each caracter has a coordenate (line, column) ex: 'H' = (1,2).
EX:

```
       0    1    2    3    4
  0 ((‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’, ‘E’),
  1  (‘F’, ‘G’, ‘H’, ‘I’, ‘J’),
  2  (‘ ’, ‘L’, ‘M’, ‘N’, ‘O’),
  3  (‘P’, ‘Q’, ‘R’, ‘S’, ‘T’),
  4  (‘U’, ‘V’, ‘X’, ‘Z’, ‘.’))
```

What a did next was a function that takes the key the previous function returned and then returns the coordenates of any caracter that belongs to the key ive given.

```
def obtain_code1(car, key):

    key = key_gen(letters)

    if car in range(key(0, 4)):
        lin = '0'
    if car in range(key(5, 9)):
        lin = '1'
    if car in range(key(10, 14)):
        lin = '2'
    if car in range(key(15, 19)):
        lin = '3'
    if car in range(key(20, 24)):
        lin = '4'
    if car in range(key(0, 4, 5)):
        col = '0'
    if car in range(key(5, 9, 5)):
        col = '1'
    if car in range(key(10, 14, 5)):
        col = '2'
    if car in range(key(15, 19, 5)):
        col = '3'
    if car in range(key(20, 24, 5)):
        col  = '4'
    codcar = lin + col
    return codcar
```

The result in the python shell should be:

```
>>>obtain_code1('Q', key)

'31'
```

but I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'key' is not defined
```

I dont undersatnd why it says that. Maybe its a stupid mistake but im a beginner in python. Again sorry for the long code but im really struggling in here. Plz help.

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete code? Because I do not see `chave` variable defined any where in your code (due to which you are getting error)

Comment: im sorry. the original code had variables names wrtten in other language so i translated it to english but i forgot to translate that last name.

Comment: What do you expect the following to do: `key(20, 24, 5)`. I would expect it to throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: What do you except `key(0, 4)` to do? It's not a function, and tuples are not callable...

Comment: Also, why the space in your letters?

Comment: Your function is not named `key`, it's named `key_gen1`. Why are you calling `key`? Are you a beginner in python, or a beginner in programming? @PedroGonçalves

Comment: damn it. sorry for wasting your time i just saw that I completly messed up everything but thanks for the answers.

Comment: @PedroGonçalves best to just leave your code the way it was when you ran it. Translating the name's doesn't help, especially if you do it manually (you're bound to mess up). Python programmers will understand your code whether the names are in english or spanish.

Comment: @CharlesAddis im a beginner in programming and python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if i want to write a sentence with code i defined ex: 'i like pizza', i need to have a space in my generated key

Answer (score 1):

The brute-force way to do what you are trying to accomplish is to simply iterate over each row:

```
In [2]: key
Out[2]: 
(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
 ('F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'),
 (' ', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'),
 ('P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'),
 ('U', 'V', 'X', 'Z', '.'))

In [3]: idx = None

In [4]: for i,row in enumerate(key):
    ...:     for j, letter in enumerate(row):
    ...:         if letter == 'Q':
    ...:             idx = (i,j)
    ...:             
    ...:             
    ...:             

In [5]: idx
Out[5]: (3, 1)
```

The performance here is O(n) with the size of your search space. But you could improve that if you changed your data structures.